# how to change multi dates color in caldroid

Tags: android, caldroid

Code block has been formatted for better visibility

guys i'm trying to change color of different dates

```
void changeEventDateColor(){
    DatabaseHandler databaseHandler=new DatabaseHandler(this);
    List<Contact> contacts=databaseHandler.getAllContacts();
    //String[] date=new String[contacts.size()];

    String date="11/02/2016T09:27:37Z";

    //for(Contact cn: contacts){

    //date=cn.get_date();

    String[] d=date.split("/");
    Log.d("date   ============", d[0]+"/"+d[1]+"/"+d[2]);

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    try {
        Date parsedDate = formatter.parse(date);
        Log.d("date   ============", parsedDate+"");
        Log.d("date   ============", formatter.format(parsedDate));
        caldroidFragment.setBackgroundResourceForDate(R.color.blue,parsedDate);
        caldroidFragment.refreshView();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //}
}
```

anyone please tell whats wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SimpleDateFormat

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

instead of

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
```